# valueBox to show Maximum of a column selected from selectInput using a reactive function

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, reactive

New to R Shiny. When I am trying to implement a valueBox using a reactive function, where the reactive function changes through choices of column names, based off of user select, to then where I would like to produce the maximum from the selected column.
Had an array of errors from cannot find object "Ordered_Product_Sales" even though it was clearly there to cannot apply non function.

Here is my code

```
library(shinythemes)
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(lubridate)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "black", #theme = shinytheme("cyborg"),
dashboardHeader("Metric Tracker"),
dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
          menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "Dashboard", icon = icon("city"))))

dashboardBody(fluidRow(
tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "Dashboard",
box(width = 4,title = "Inputs", solidHeader = TRUE, status = "warning", selectInput("value", "1st Value to Track:" , choices =  c("Units_Ordered", "Buy_Box_Percentage", "Ordered_Product_Sales", "Session_Percentage","aov"), selected = "Ordered_Product_Sales", multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE)
valueBoxOutput("max"), valueBoxOutput("min", width = 3)      
      ),

server <- function(input, output){

g <- reactive({
  (input$value)
})

output$max <- renderValueBox({
#maxi <-  max(metricx2[,get(g())])
valueBox(maxi, subtitle = "Max")
```

I just simply want to display the maximum value from the column that has been selected in selectInput. The reactive switches between the names of the columns/selectInput choices.
Metricx2 is the data I want to pull the maximum value from.

If you need additional code let me know as this is only a snippet and i could have left something informative out.

Thanks for the help, I'm trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show enough code for me to see what the problem is. Here is a minimal working example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic boxes"),
    dashboardSidebar(
        selectInput('column', 'Column:', names(mtcars))
    ),
    dashboardBody(
            valueBoxOutput("vbox")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$vbox <- renderValueBox({
        valueBox(
            paste('Maximum of', input$column),
            max(mtcars[[input$column]])
        )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This worked Regardless of you needing additional data. Thank you